# What nullability get columns when the DDL doesn't explicitly sets it?

Tags: sql-server

In the system I frequently work on I often see DB schema change scripts that when creating or modifying columns doesn't states if columns are nullable or not (I know it's good practice to be explicit, but not everyone follows that). The concrete cases I'm wondering about are those:

```
--Create a new table or add a new column to an existing table
CREATE TABLE dbo.test (SomeColumn INT) ;
ALTER TABLE dbo.test ADD SomeColumn INT ;
```

In those cases the instructions don't explicitly state if the new column if `NULL` or `NOT NULL`. Question is, which actually is? On what depends?

```
--Change the definition of an existing column
ALTER TABLE dbo.test ALTER COLUMN SomeColumn BIGINT ;
```

In that case, an existing column definition is changed (suppose to enlarge a data type) but again the script fails to state nullability. What would the column end being, null or not null? Or will it preserve its previous state? Depending on what?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a `create table` It depends.

Most clients will [`SET ANSI_NULL_DFLT_ON ON`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187375.aspx) which means that the columns will end up `NULL` (except for columns in a PK where `NOT NULL` is always the default).

But it is possible to `SET ANSI_NULL_DFLT_OFF ON` In which case they will be `NOT NULL`.

If both are `OFF` it falls back to the `is_ansi_null_default_on` database option.

So best to be explicit.

In an `alter table` it always acts as though ansi defaults are on and the column will end up allowing `null` unless otherwise specified. When altering an existing column this takes no account of its existing state so `not null` must be specified explicitly to retain that behaviour.

Comment: Bottom line, always specify nullability in each column just to be sure. Thanks!